# @input event firing late and getting an error: "Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "type"."

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm checking for the @input event on the first QInput. It seems that the only QInputs that are giving me trouble are the ones that have the type as "number". I have a function that checks everytime the field is empty but it only fires once I press outside of the QInput. I'm pretty sure I have everything correct but I keep on getting errors and the events are firing late. The error I'm getting is as follows: "Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "type". The component that is giving me trouble is about 900 lines of code so I'll just attach some of it.
This is the full error:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "type".

found in

---> <QInput>
       <QModal>
         <QDialog>
           <Anonymous>
             <QPageContainer>
               <QLayout>
                 <MyLayout> at src/layouts/MyLayout.vue
                   <App> at src/App.vue
                     <Root>
warn    @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:587
assertProp  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1639
validateProp    @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1556
updateChildComponent    @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2845
prepatch    @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4140
patchVnode  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5921
updateChildren  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5818
patchVnode  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5932
updateChildren  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5818
patchVnode  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5932
updateChildren  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5818
patchVnode  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5932
updateChildren  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5818
patchVnode  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5932
updateChildren  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5818
patchVnode  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5932
updateChildren  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5818
patchVnode  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5932
patch   @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6092
Vue._update @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2666
updateComponent @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2784
get @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3138
run @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3215
flushSchedulerQueue @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2977
(anonymous) @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1833
flushCallbacks  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1754
Promise.then (async)        
microTimerFunc  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1802
nextTick    @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1846
queueWatcher    @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3064
update  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3205
notify  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:693
reactiveSetter  @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1010
proxySetter @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3296
__onBlur    @   input.js?5e06:45
(anonymous) @   input.js?5e06:40
setTimeout (async)      
__onInputBlur   @   input.js?5e06:39
invoker @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2023
fn._withTask.fn._withTask   @   vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1822

Component code below: 

<template>
  <div>
    <div id="mainjob">
      <div>
        <div class="secondarycolor">
          <h5 id="jobheader"> Job Center </h5>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="secondarycolor">Filter By:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-center">
          <q-tabs color="secondary" align="justify" inverted v-model="selectedtab">
            <q-tab default name="searchbyid" label="Search by ID" slot="title"/>
            <q-tab name="customfilter" label="Custom Filters" slot="title"/>
            <q-tab name="notpickedup" label="Machines Not Picked Up" slot="title" @select="notpickedup()"/>
            <q-tab-pane name="searchbyid">
              <div class="row justify-center" id="repairid">
                <q-input type="number" placeholder="Repair ID" @input="RepairId()" class="inputspace" v-model="repairid" color="secondary"/>
              </div>
            </q-tab-pane>
            <q-tab-pane name="customfilter">
              <div id="filterbox">
                <div id="selectbox">
                  <div  id="selectboxsub">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div>
                        <q-select
                          class="inputspace"
                          multiple
                          color="secondary"
                          filter
                          placeholder="Select Filters"
                          v-model="filtersselected"
                          :options="filteroptions"
                          @input="filterchanged()"
                          :display-value="`${filtersselected.length} filters selected`"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <q-btn icon="clear" color="secondary" @click="clearfilters()" class="inputspace">
                          <q-tooltip anchor="bottom middle" self="top middle" :offset="[10, 10]" color="secondary" @click="showing = false">
                            Clear Filters
                          </q-tooltip>
                        </q-btn>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-center" id="filterinput" v-if="filtersselected.length>0">
                  <div>
                    <q-input @input="searchbyfilter()" placeholder="Customer First Name" color="secondary" v-model="fname" class="inputspace" id="fname" v-if="containsvar('cusfname')"/>
                    <q-input @input="searchbyfilter()" placeholder="Customer Last Name" color="secondary" v-model="lname" class="inputspace" id="lname" v-if="containsvar('cuslname')"/>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <q-select
                      class="inputspace"
                      id="brand"
                      color="secondary"
                      filter
                      placeholder="Machine Brand"
                      v-model="brand"
                      :options="Brands"
                      @input="brandchanged(), searchbyfilter()"
                      v-if="containsvar('brand')"
                    />
                    <q-select
                      class="inputspace"
                      id="color"
                      color="secondary"
                      filter
                      placeholder="Machine Color"
                      v-model="color"
                      :options="Colors"
                      @input="colorchanged(), searchbyfilter()"
                      v-if="containsvar('color')"
                    />
                    <q-select
                      class="inputspace"
                      id="type"
                      color="secondary"
                      filter
                      placeholder="Machine Type"
                      v-model="type"
                      :options="Types"
                      @input="typechanged(), searchbyfilter()"
                       v-if="containsvar('type')"
                    />
                    <q-input @input="searchbyfilter()" placeholder="Model" color="secondary" v-model="model" class="inputspace" id="model"  v-if="containsvar('model')"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column">
                    <q-checkbox @input="searchbyfilter()" label="Warranty" color="secondary" v-model="warranty" class="inputspace" id="warranty"  v-if="containsvar('warranty')"/>
                    <q-checkbox @input="searchbyfilter()" label="Purchased Here" color="secondary" v-model="purchased" class="inputspace" id="purchased"  v-if="containsvar('purchased')"/>
                    <q-checkbox @input="searchbyfilter()" label="Rush Service" color="secondary" v-model="rushservice" class="inputspace" id="rushservice"  v-if="containsvar('rushservice')"/>
                    <q-checkbox @input="searchbyfilter()" label="Completed" color="secondary" v-model="completed" class="inputspace" id="completed"  v-if="containsvar('completed')"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </q-tab-pane>
            <q-tab-pane name="notpickedup">
            </q-tab-pane>
          </q-tabs>
        </div>
        <div>
          <center v-if="filteredbyid.length==0&&selectedtab=='searchbyid'">
            <h6 class="secondarycolor">No Results</h6>
          </center>
          <center v-if="customfilters.length==0&&selectedtab=='customfilter'">
            <h6 class="secondarycolor">No Results</h6>
          </center>
          <div class="row justify-center">
            <div class="row justify-center">
              <q-card color="secondary" dark class="q-ma-sm" v-for="(repair,index) in jobs" :key="index">
                <q-card-title>
                  <i><span class="title"># </span></i>
                  <span class="title">{{ repair.RepairID }}</span>
                </q-card-title>
                <q-card-main>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="titles">
                      <span ><b>Name:</b></span><br>
                      <span><b>Phone Number:</b></span> <br>
                      <span><b>Brand:</b></span> <br>
                      <span><b>Type:</b></span> <br>
                      <span><b>Color:</b></span> <br>
                      <span><b>Model:</b></span> <br>
                      <span><b>Problem:</b></span> <br>
                      <span><b>Phone Number:</b></span> <br>
                      <span><b>Warranty:</b></span> <br>
                      <span><b>Purchased Here: </b></span> <br>
                      <span><b>Rush Service: </b></span> <br>
                      <span><b>Date Received: </b></span> <br>
                      <span><b>Status: </b></span> <br>
                      <span v-if="repair.Hours!=null"><b>Hours: </b></span> <br>
                      <span v-if="repair.Hours!=null"><b>Pick Up Date: </b></span> <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                      <span>{{ repair.FirstName + " " + repair.LastName }}</span> <br>
                      <span>{{ repair.PhoneNumber }}</span> <br>
                      <span>{{ repair.Brand }}</span> <br>
                      <span>{{ repair.Type }}</span> <br>
                      <span>{{ repair.Color }}</span> <br>
                      <span>{{ repair.Model }}</span> <br>
                      <span>{{ repair.Problem }}</span> <br>
                      <span>{{ repair.PhoneNumber }}</span> <br>
                      <q-icon name="check_box" v-if="repair.Warranty==1" />
                      <q-icon name="check_box_outline_blank" v-if="repair.Warranty==0" /> <br>
                      <q-icon name="check_box" v-if="repair.Purchased==1" />
                      <q-icon name="check_box_outline_blank" v-if="repair.Purchased==0" /> <br>
                      <q-icon name="check_box" v-if="repair.RushService==1" />
                      <q-icon name="check_box_outline_blank" v-if="repair.RushService==0" /> <br>
                      <span> {{ getdatestring(repair.DateReceived) }} </span> <br>
                      <span v-if="repair.Hours!=null"> Completed </span>
                      <span v-if="repair.Hours==null"> In Progress </span> <br> 
                      <span v-if="repair.Hours!=null"> {{repair.Hours}} </span> <br>
                      <span v-if="repair.Hours!=null&&repair.DatePickedUp!=null"> {{getdatestring(repair.DatePickedUp)}} </span>
                      <span v-if="repair.Hours!=null&&repair.DatePickedUp==null"> Pickup Pending </span> <br>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </q-card-main>
                <q-card-separator />
                <q-card-actions>
                  <q-btn icon="playlist_add" class="inputspace" v-if="repair.Hours==null" @click="addpart(repair.RepairID)">
                    <q-tooltip anchor="bottom middle" self="top middle" :offset="[10, 10]" color="secondary" @click="showing = false">
                      Add Part
                    </q-tooltip>
                  </q-btn>
                  <q-btn icon="list_alt" color="secondary" class="inputspace" @click="getpartslist(repair.RepairID)">
                    <q-tooltip anchor="bottom middle" self="top middle" :offset="[10, 10]" color="secondary" @click="showing = false">
                      View All Parts
                    </q-tooltip>
                  </q-btn>
                  <q-btn icon="done" color="secondary" class="inputspace" v-if="repair.Hours==null" @click="completejob(repair.RepairID)">
                    <q-tooltip anchor="bottom middle" self="top middle" :offset="[10, 10]" color="secondary" @click="showing = false">
                      Complete Job
                    </q-tooltip>
                  </q-btn>
                  <q-btn icon="local_shipping" color="secondary" class="inputspace" v-if="repair.Hours!=null&&repair.DatePickedUp==null" @click="pickupmachinery(repair.RepairID)">
                    <q-tooltip anchor="bottom middle" self="top middle" :offset="[10, 10]" color="secondary" @click="showing = false">
                      Pick Up Machine
                    </q-tooltip>
                  </q-btn>
                </q-card-actions>
              </q-card>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <q-dialog
        v-model="addpartdialog"
        prevent-close
        >
          <span slot="title">
            <span class="secondarycolor row justify-center"> Add Parts </span>
          </span>
          <template slot="message"> 
            <div class="row justify-center addpartborder">
              <div class="column addpartsideborder">
                <center><p class="secondarycolor">Part Number: </p></center>
                <q-input type="text" placeholder="Part Number" v-model="partnumber" color="secondary" class="inputspace"/>
              </div>
              <div class="column addpartsideborder">
                <center><p class="secondarycolor"> Quantity: </p></center>
                <q-input type="number" placeholder="Quantity" v-model="numquantity" color="secondary" class="inputspace"/>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <center><p class="secondarycolor"> Description: </p></center>
                <q-input type="text" placeholder="Part Description" v-model="partdescription" color="secondary" class="inputspace"/>
              </div>
            </div><center>
            <div>
              <q-btn label="Add Part" color="secondary" @click="addparts()" :disable="disableaddparts"/>
            </div></center>
          </template>
          <span slot="buttons" slot-scope="props">
            <span>
              <q-btn label="Done" color="secondary" @click="done()" class="row justify-center"/>
            </span>
          </span>
        </q-dialog>
        <q-dialog
          v-model="addpartsuccess"
          color="secondary"
        >
          <span slot="title" class="secondarycolor"> Part Addition Request </span>
          <span slot="message"> Part Added Successfully </span>
        </q-dialog>
        <q-dialog
          v-model="pickupsuccess"
          color="secondary"
        >
          <span slot="title" class="secondarycolor"> Pickup Request </span>
          <span slot="message"> Date Added Successfully </span>
        </q-dialog>
        <q-dialog
              v-model="partslistdialog"
              prevent-close
        >
          <span slot="title"> 
            <span class="secondarycolor row justify-center">Parts List </span>
          </span>
          <template slot="message" class="row justify-center"> 
            <span v-if="partslist.length==0"> No parts entered for this machine </span>
            <table class="secondarycolor" v-else>
              <tr class="tableborderbottom">
                <th> Part Name </th>
                <th> Part Number </th>
                <th class="no-border"> Quantity </th>
              </tr>
              <tr v-for="(part, index) in partslist" :key="index">
                <td><center> {{ part.PartName }} </center></td>
                <td><center> {{ part.PartNumber }} </center></td>
                <td class="no-border"><center> {{ part.Quantity }} </center></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </template>
          <span slot="buttons" slot-scope="props">
            <q-btn label="Go Back" color="secondary" @click="partslistgoback()"/>
          </span>
        </q-dialog>
        <q-dialog
          v-model="terminatejob"
          color="secondary"
          prevent-close
        >
          <span slot="title">
            <span class="secondarycolor row justify-center"> Complete Job </span>
          </span>
          <span slot="message">
            <div class="row justify-center">
              <div class="column">
                <span class="secondarycolor justify-center row"> Hours Worked: </span>
                <q-input type="number" placeholder="Hours" color="secondary" v-model="hours" class="inputspace"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </span>
          <span slot="buttons" slot-scope="props">
            <q-btn label="Submit" color="secondary" class="inputspace" @click="finishjob()" :disable="disablefinishbtn"/>
            <q-btn label="Cancel" color="secondary" class="inputspace" @click="hoursgoback()"/>
          </span>
        </q-dialog>
        <q-dialog
          v-model="pickup"
          color="secondary"
          prevent-close
        >
          <span slot="title">
            <span class="secondarycolor row justify-center"> Pick Up Machine </span>
          </span>
          <span slot="message">
            <div class="row justify-center">
              <div class="column">
                <span class="secondarycolor justify-center row"> Date Picked Up: </span>
                <q-input type="Date" placeholder="Pick Up Date" color="secondary" v-model="pickupdate" class="inputspace"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </span>
          <span slot="buttons" slot-scope="props">
            <q-btn label="Submit" color="secondary" class="inputspace" @click="pickupmachine()" :disable="disablepickupbtn"/>
            <q-btn label="Cancel" color="secondary" class="inputspace" @click="pickupgoback()"/>
          </span>
        </q-dialog>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

data () {
    return {
      selectedtab: 'searchbyid',
      repairid: null,
      filtersselected: [],
      model: "",
      fname: "",
      lname: "",
      brand: null,
      color: null,
      type: null,
      warranty: false,
      purchased: false,
      rushservice: false,
      completed: false,
      servercolors: [],
      serverbrands: [],
      servertypes: [],
      filteroptions: [
        {
          label: "Select All",
          value: "selectall"
        },
        {
          label:"Customer First Name",
          value:"cusfname"
        },
        {
          label:"Customer Last Name",
          value:"cuslname"
        },
        {
          label:"Brand of Machine",
          value:"brand"
        },
        {
          label:"Type of Machine",
          value:"type"
        },
        {
          label:"Model of Machine",
          value:"model"
        },
        {
          label:"Color",
          value:"color"
        },
        {
          label:"Warranty",
          value:"warranty"
        },
        {
          label:"Purchased Here",
          value:"purchased"
        },
        {
          label:"Rush Service",
          value:"rushservice"
        },
        {
          label: "Completed Jobs",
          value: "completed"
        }
      ],
      filteredbyid: [],
      customfilters: [],
      machinesnotpickedup: [],
      partnumber: "",
      numquantity: 0,
      partdescription: "",
      addpartdialog: false,
      addpartrepairidchosen: null,
      addpartsuccess: false,
      partslistdialog: false,
      partslistrepairidchosen: null,
      partslist: [],
      terminatejob: false,
      hours: 0,
      finishjobrepairid: null,
      finishjobsuccess: false,
      pickupdate: null,
      pickup: false,
      pickuprepairid: null,
      pickupsuccess: false
    }
  },
RepairId: function () {
      console.log(this.repairid)
      if(this.repairid==null)
      {
        this.filteredbyid=[]
      }
      else
      {
        this.$Socket.emit('findrepairbyid', {
          RepairID: this.repairid
        }, (data) => {
          this.filteredbyid=data
        })
      }
    },
```

Comment: I've added the full error in the code section. If anyone has any idea what my problem would be I would appreciate any input. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello I have a similar problem. I use 'q-btn-toggle'. Have you ever solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Its been a while so OP probably solved this problem, but, for anyone coming later:**

**The error message describes the WHY** : 'Invalid **prop**: custom validator check failed for prop "type"'.

This happens because the prop is receiving an untreated/unaccepted value. To fix this just check your framework [documentation](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#introduction) or your own component for the named **prop** and check what are the values it accepts, in this case the **prop** "type" from the **component** "input" from the framework **Quasar** accepts:
[the following values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA4pN.png). So if you set anything other than the accepted values it will show this error.

**The error message also describes WHERE**, this part i find trickier, because if you have many pages with similar DOM tree structures the **error** will only show the components names, so you ofter will have to look for the context, like, WHICH view is generating the error, after WHAT action it occurs.

Reading the error message it gives the location of the error like this

`found in ---> <QInput>`...

...`<Root>`

Showing the DOM tree starting by the component generating the error, i usually can find the component after some digging.

In OPs case they mention some blur event delay and the error message agrees, showing this in the last few lines.

- `__onBlur    @   input.js?5e06:45`
- `(anonymous) @   input.js?5e06:40`
- `setTimeout (async)`
- `__onInputBlur   @   input.js?5e06:39`

This can help you single out the component where the error is originating by finding where a **@blur** is being used and when it occurs, based on OPs post i don't think the error is originating from the posted code.